# How to execute a java program from another java program in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javac

I'm trying to run a java program, called Test.java from another java program Demo.java. Both programs are in the same package, I'm doing something like this:

```
try{
                System.out.println("Executing another client");
                runProcess("javac -cp gridgain-examples C:/Users/Desktop/gridgain/examples/src/main/java/apache/ignite/schemas/Test.java");
                System.out.println("******");
                runProcess("java -cp gridgain-examples C:/Users/Desktop/gridgain/examples/src/main/java/apache/ignite/schemas/Test.java");
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And the runProcess and printlines methods are:

```
 private static void printLines(String cmd, InputStream ins) throws Exception {


   String line = null;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(ins));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(cmd + " " + line);
    }
  }

private static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception {
    Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    printLines(command + " stdout:", pro.getInputStream());
    printLines(command + " stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());
    pro.waitFor();
    System.out.println(command + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());
  }
```

But it's not executing. Please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Are there any exceptions thrown?

Comment: No, when it goes into while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) line, it goes into an unending loop, it seems. The program keeps executing and doesn't end.

Comment: don't know whether this is the cause of the problem, but your second call seems wrong, it is still referencing java files, not class files

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "C:\Users\Desktop\gridgain\examples\src\main\java\apache\ignite\schemas\Test.java"?

I'd comment this but don't have the reputation :(